# Strange... ListView is showing just part of the data

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

So... I have Fragment that contains ListView.

I also have `private ArrayList<ComicListItem> listViewData;` That is defined inside fragment class. In that List I store data to display it with ListView.

I have `public class ListViewOfComicsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ComicListItem>` too.

I populate listViewData with data inside

```
 @Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)
```

and the data is there, I saw via debugger.

Next thing I do:

```
@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        ArrayList<ComicListItem> itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(listViewData != null)
        {
            for (ComicListItem cli : listViewData)
                itemArrayList.add(cli);
        }
        // I added this one for test, and it is the only one that is shown inside ListView
        itemArrayList.add(new ComicListItem(true, "aaaa", null, "eeee"));


        listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_view_comics);             
        adapter = new ListViewOfComicsAdapter(getContext(), R.id.list_view_comics, itemArrayList);
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // no change, really
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I am copying values one by one in other `ArrayList<ComicListItem>`. Why? Because I had same problem earlier when passing `listViewData` that I populated to `ListViewOfComicsAdapter`'s constructor  so I just copied data in `itemArrayList` like this, and that worked for a short time (data was visible).

Now, only visible item is one that I added manually (for a test purpose). In debugger I see 31 item in `itemArrayList` and they are not null.

All data I add to `listViewData` is there but not visible inside ListView.

`getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` from adapter is called only once.

I have `list_view_item.xml` and list item that shows up uses it.

I am in pain, someone please help.

## UPDATE - Adapter code

```
public class ListViewOfComicsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ComicListItem>
{
    Context mContext;
    ComicListItem data[] = null;

public ListViewOfComicsAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ComicListItem> items)
{
    super(context, resource, items);
    mContext = context;
    try
    {
        data = new ComicListItem[items.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
            data[i] = items.get(i);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("problem", "no items to display in framgent");
    }
}
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    boolean recycleView = true;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_comic, parent, false);
        recycleView = false;
    }
    // object item based on the position
    ComicListItem objectItem = data[position];
    ComicStorageInfo info = new ComicStorageInfo(null, 0, position + 1, 1, objectItem.fileName);
    TextView textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_comic);
    textViewItem.setText(objectItem.date);
    if(!recycleView)
    {
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), App.getInstance().readImageFromInternalStorage(info.getFileName()));
        textViewItem.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drawable, null, null);
    }
    else
    {
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comic_progressbar);
        new ReadImageFromStorage(textViewItem, progressBar).execute(info.getFileName());
    }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the adaptor code?

Comment: I have updated question with adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that I have 2 fragments and `OnResume()` of second is called after and it write it over first one. AND they have same ID so it always writes on first fragment. Enough to confuse me.